# Comparing object with Nothing in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a code

```
Dim drQues As DataRow = dtQuestion.AsEnumerable()
             .First(Function(uqno) uqno.Field(Of Int32)("uniqueqno") = drqno("uniqueqno"))
```

I want to check if `drQues` is `Nothing`

I tried

```
If Not drQues <> Nothing THEN
```

but it says

> <> is not defined for System.Data.DataRow and System.Data.DataRow

how can I check if there was a row for specified condition in linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Is` or `IsNot` where the usual comparison operators are not defined.

`If drQues Is Nothing Then`

Comment: `IsNot` was what I needed :)